# Connect service container to db container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and started to play with it on my small project.

I have dockerized the service itself with the following Docker file:

```
ROM adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot AS DEPENDENCIES_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew $APP_HOME
COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
RUN ./gradlew build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN ./gradlew build

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.7_10-alpine AS FINAL
ENV JAR_TEMPLATE=myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=myapp.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=DEPENDENCIES_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$JAR_TEMPLATE .
RUN mv $JAR_TEMPLATE $ARTIFACT_NAME
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "budget-calculator.jar"]
```

Side note - I know that there's a problem that I'm always copying `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` - but I'm not sure how to solve it at the moment.

After that I wanted to connect my service to a Postgres DB with docker-compose using this confirmation:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: myapp
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "db"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend

  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: myapp-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp
    ports:
      - 5436:5436
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
```

After that I've updated my application.properties file to indicate that the DB link is on the other container as follow:

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5436/myapp
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=secret
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5436/myapp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Now I had 2 problems:

1. While I assumed that `build: .` will rebuild my image every time
   that I'm running `docker-compose up` if something changed in
   practice I saw that it's not the case.
2. When the backend service starts flyway (a migration DB library) try
   to connect to the database and cannot resolve the connection.

I've seen online that the usage of `- links` is deprecated and I should use the `networks` but both do not seem to work - what am I missing?

Comment: Postgres runs on port 5432 by default. Are you sure you mean 5436?

Comment: I just changed it because I have another instance running no this port right now - it doesn't really matter to me to be honest

Comment: But if you're trying to connect to port 5436 on the postgres container, and postgres is listening on port 5432, it's not going to work. You haven't provided any configuration that would cause postgres to listen on a different port.

Comment: Oh, you're right - I'm mapping the internal port as 5436 as well!

Comment: And you're pointing your jdbc url at the wrong port as well (`jdbc:postgresql://db:5436/myapp`), because that's connecting to the container directly and won't be effected by the port forwarding.

Comment: Yap, just seen it - and answered my question to make sure it's well documented :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with my configurations, the first one - the internal port of `Postgres` was configured as `5436` while the default port of the image is `5432` (I've updated both of them to `5432`)

the second one, in order to pass the IP of the DB to the service I've added the following environment variables to the service image:

```
environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/budget
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: secret
      SPRING_FLYWAY_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/budget
      SPRING_FLYWAY_USER: postgres
      SPRING_FLYWAY_PASSWORD: secret
```

So my current working configuration is this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: app-service
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/myapp
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: secret
      SPRING_FLYWAY_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/myapp
      SPRING_FLYWAY_USER: postgres
      SPRING_FLYWAY_PASSWORD: secret

  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=secret
    volumes:
      - myapp_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  myapp_data:
```